# escaping double quote and comma for to generate CSV

Tags: apex-code

Here is the data that I need to parse them as CSV.

Actually, I am making CSV string which I will need to import to another system.
Basically, I append comma between each field that I query from DB.

```
Column1 :
Testing

Column 2: 
<p class="MsoNormal" style=""><b><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; ">This is just a test, test2, test3</span></b><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; "></span></p>

Column 3:
Blah Blah
```

Now, I am facing problem of retaining double quotes and comma (as I need to save as in HTML format of this text).

I try to append double quote for for the column2 data at the start and end, but it doesn't work out.

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: base64 encode <-> decode

Comment: what did you use to parse?

Comment: I would use a separator that doesn't exist anywhere in the current text. Like § but that's probably a bad solution. Just putting it out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String has the instance method *[escapeCSV](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm)*, this should be what you need.

If you need something different you could always use *replace* to replace any characters you want to escape with escapeCharacter+originalCharacter eg. (" => \").

Comment: perfect for my requirement.